# Creating ranges of letters from array to generate a Regex rule

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a small issue when trying to create a Regex rule to exclude some characters in a given range: ie. ^[a-b-d-z] character 'c' will be exclude for that range.

Here is the code:

```
    const excludeLetters = [ 'C', 'F', 'W' ];
    const generateAlphabet = () => {

       let alphabet = [];
       let start = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
       let last  = 'Z'.charCodeAt(0);

       for ( let i = start; i <= last; ++i ) {
          alphabet.push( String.fromCharCode( i ) );
       }

       return alphabet;
    };

    const alphabet = generateAlphabet();
    let chunks = []; 

    for ( let i = 0; i < excludeLetters.length; i++ ) {
        if( alphabet.includes( excludeLetters[ i ] ) ) {
            let index = alphabet.indexOf( excludeLetters[ i ] );
            if ( index > -1 ) {
    
                alphabet.splice( index, 1 );
                chunks.push( alphabet.splice( 0, index ) );
      
                console.log( '1 ', excludeLetters[ i ] );
                console.log( '2 ---> ', index );
                console.log( '3 ---> ', alphabet );
                console.log( '4 ---> ', chunks );
            }
        }
    }

    const addRange = ( arr ) => {

        let range = [];

        for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    
            range.push( arr[ i ][ 0 ] );
            range.push( arr[ i ][ arr[ i ].length - 1 ] );
        }

        return range.join('-');

    };

   const regexRange = addRange( chunks );
   console.log( 'regexRange ---> ', regexRange );
```

// Output

```
"1 ", "C"
"2 ---> ", 2
"3 ---> ", ["D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
"4 ---> ", [["A", "B"]]

"1 ", "F"
"2 ---> ", 2
"3 ---> ", ["G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
"4 ---&gt; ", [["A", "B"], ["D", "E"]]

"1 ", "W"
"2 ---> ", 16
"3 ---> ", ["X", "Y", "Z"]
"4 ---> ", [["A", "B"], ["D", "E"], ["G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V"]]

"regexRange ---> ", "A-B-D-E-G-V"
```

I am expecting **"A-B-D-E-G-V-X-Z"** and regexRange is "A-B-D-E-G-V" so i am missing this chunk ["X", "Z"].

Any help will be appreciate it. Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/ao8dj76b/1/

Comment: `^[a-b-d-z]` - This character class contains: characters from `a` to `b`, `d` to `z` and a dash `-`

Answer (score 0):

Add `chunks.push(alphabet)` before `addRange(chunks)`.

BTW I think the regex should be `[A-BD-EG-VX-Z]`, no hyphen between each range

Comment: Thanks to point that out. That works like a charm. I've changed the the addRange() function to get [A-BD-EG-VX-Z] as you suggested, however [A-B-D-E-G-V-X-Z] also works as expected.